# Saving changes from 1 record using Entity Framework is updating 2 records in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database containing sales of customers. I am trying to update 1 record using Entity Framework, but when I check my database, two records have been updated

My table is called `Customers` and has these two records:

```
NameID    GenderID      ItemID          ShopID    Cost      
--------------------------------------------------------
587651    1              464             9         NULL 
587651    1              512             9         NULL
```

I want to update the first record which I am trying to do using Entity Framework.

This is my code:

```
using (var context = new Customers())
{
    var _customers = (from all in context.Customers
                      where (all.NameID == 587651) && 
                            (all.GenderID == 1) &&
                            (all.ItemID == 464) && 
                            (all.ShopID == 9)
                      select all).First();
    _customers.Cost = 100;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

After saving the changes I get the following in my database:

```
NameID    GenderID      ItemID         ShopID     Cost      
--------------------------------------------------------
587651    1              464             9         100  
587651    1              512             9         100
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It seems that nameid is mistaken for a primary key

Comment: Are you sure the code you are showing is the actual code that is giving the problem? Even though there is a problem (with the single ampersand on the where predicate) with the code, you are doing a `First()` and then modifying a single entity (whether that one is the right one or not, it's only one) though you are showing two entities updated.

So either this is not the actual problematic code, and something is missing on the sample code you are showing, or there is something else going on at the database level (triggers, or whatnot)

Comment: @DanielWyatt is this database first or code first? If "nameid" is taken on the model as the primary key but it is not on the database, then that MAY explain it, but then you have to show how your model is configured

Comment: Yes this is the code I am using. I am selecting the first record and updating that one.

Comment: @DanielWyatt then EF is taking `NameID` as the primary key however that's not defined as the PK on the database provider... your model translation from the database is wrong (that wouldn't happen if EF is constructing the database or if you had reverse-engineered it). The SQL sentence it's generating would be something like `UPDATE customers SET Cost = 100 WHERE NameID = 587651`, which would match what you are seeing.

Comment: Please share Costomer mapping (`modelBuilder`) codes.

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to see what SQL is being generated by EF to do the update - it might point to where the problem lies, and possibly prove @jcl right about NameId being considered a PK.

Comment: @DanielWyatt Which is the primary key of your `Customers` table?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have now solved this, thanks to the comments above. The code that defined my table looked like this:

```
public partial class Customers
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NameJID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int GenderID { get; set; }

    public int? ItemID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ShopID { get; set; }

    public double? Cost { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the primary key only includes NameID, GenderID and ShopID. Notice also how *ItemID* is nullable. I have now changed the code to this:

```
public partial class Customers
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NameJID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int GenderID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ShopID { get; set; }

    public double? Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: indeed, all PK columns have to be defined because they are used as concurrency tokens for all CRUD operations (in particular, they are used to identify the tuples)